# try to upload a file from a UWP app to flask restful web api, failed

Tags: c#, flask, uwp

I'm trying to build a UWP application using C#. And I also build a restful web api using flask on my other device(i.e. raspberry pi). But when I tried to upload an image from UWP app to raspberry pi through the api, the raspberry pi didn't receive the file while the request seemed to be successful.

so, after running the web api on raspberry pi and then running the uwp app on windows 10, I got this return: "no file".

This is the code for my UWP app

```
public async void Upload_FileAsync(string WebServiceURL, string 
FilePathToUpload){
    IStorageFile storageFile = await 
    StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(FilePathToUpload);

    IRandomAccessStream stream = await 
    storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    HttpStreamContent streamfile = new HttpStreamContent(stream);
    HttpMultipartFormDataContent httpContents = new 
                      HttpMultipartFormDataContent();

    httpContents.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
    httpContents.Add(streamfile, "file");

    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(
                       new Uri(WebServiceURL), httpContents);
    string stringReadResult = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    textBox.Text = stringReadResult;
}
```

This is how I call the function

```
Upload_FileAsync("http://192.168.0.111:5000/upload", 
             "c:\\pictures\\testImage3.jpg");
```

---

This is the code for rest api

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import werkzeug, os

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/img'
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('file',
    type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage,
    location='files')

class PhotoUpload(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = parser.parse_args()
        if data['file'] == None:
            return "no file"
        photo = data['file']

        if photo:
            filename = 'received.png'
            photo.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
            return "file uploaded"

api.add_resource(PhotoUpload, '/upload')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

What I am expecting is: successfully upload an image to raspberry pi through the api and store it on raspberry pi. But the actual output is "no file".

And the printout on raspberry pi was this:

```
[27/Jan/2019 17:18:02] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

so it seems the request was fine but the file wasn't in the request.

Comment: Have you checked the required networking capabilities for the UWP? To do that, double-click the package.appxmanifest file in the project and go to the "Capabilities" tab.

Comment: yes, I've already checked that, private network(client & server) is selected

Comment: I assume this is definately on the client end, as the following curl command works on your flask code in its current form: `curl -i -X POST  -F 'file=@README.md' "http://localhost:5000/upload" -H 'ContentType: multipart/form-data'`

Comment: that occurs to me as well, but I have no idea what is going wrong on the UWP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem.
I forgot to parse the file name when calling this function:

```
httpContents.Add(streamfile, "file");
```

So, the proper way to do is:

```
httpContents.Add(streamfile, "file", Path.GetFileName(FilePathToUpload));
```

and now it works!